# The two components of any NTLM hash

Tags: windows, ntlm

I was trying to understand the NTLM. I know NTLM hash value consists of generally two components namely NT and LM. But do not know further about it. If anyone can help me will be great?

Comment: The algorithm is described on Wikipedia using straightforward language ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager#Protocol ), is there a part of it you don't understand?

Comment: I was not able to understand what is the function of NT and LM separately

Answer (score 0):

LM is old, NT is new, and comes in two major flavors v1 and v2, but with a few options. In all cases, this is a challenge response, allowing a principal to prove they know a password without ever sending that password. That said, LM, and v1 are broken. Only v2 has any life left in it.  This is the best reference on the tech. http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html